# Strange self-referencing constraint violation after upgrading Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-entitymanager, schemaexport

I'm using `hibernate-entitymanager` in a Spring application. I'm in the process of upgrading my Hibernate version. Narrowed it down to the exact version: when I upgrade from 4.2.1.Final to 4.2.2.Final (or anything higher than that), I'm getting the following error when my unit tests starts up and try to create the database schema:

```
2014-03-02 18:02:51,559 ERROR [SchemaExport] [main] HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table Incident add constraint FK_d91dua6gkdp1jn826adqss3aq foreign key (uuid) references Incident
2014-03-02 18:02:51,559 ERROR [SchemaExport] [main] Constraint "FK_D91DUA6GKDP1JN826ADQSS3AQ" already exists; SQL statement:

    alter table Incident
        add constraint FK_d91dua6gkdp1jn826adqss3aq
        foreign key (uuid)
        references Incident [90045-170]
```

The error does not prevent the system from working just fine, but clearly I can't go to production with such a nasty error in my system and no explanation of it.

This looks a lot like the `Incident` table has a foreign key relationship to itself, which is absolutely not the case.

I'll try to copy the *essence* here of the `Incident` entity:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@EntityListeners(value = {IncidentIdentifierPrePersistListener.class })
@FilterDefs( ... )
@Filters( ... )
public class Incident extends SomeBaseClass {

    @Id
    private String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private long identifier;

    ... a bunch more fields ...
}
```

Please let me know if I can provide anything else to help ya'all to shed a light on this. I've played around with it for hours, fruitless, and your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So your app does need to perform schema export each time it loads?

Comment: No, unit tests do (H2 in-memory database). Production will only use schema generation to validate the schema, and I've not seen any problems there. But errors in unit tests are a reason for concern. And as long as I don't understand these errors, I also won't just assume that nothing will go wrong in production. I'm upgrading Hibernate and this is a red flag for me.

Comment: Can you try removing `unique = true` from uuid? It is redundant given the field is already being marked with `@Id` don't you think?

Comment: That is a good observation, and I tinkered with it before, but reverted the change because it didn't make a difference. I'll remove it from the question, for clarity.

Comment: Ok, I think it's hard to debug. I recommend you create a minimal project to reproduce the problem, upload it to github so rest of us can test it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what happened:

- `Incident` defined a `@ManyToOne` to an entity `Project`
- `Project` **incorrectly** defined a `@ManyToMany` back to the entity `Incident` (should have been a `@OneToMany`)
- As a result Hibernate generated the awkward following constraint:

  ```
  CONSTRAINT fk909a8f241708a1e FOREIGN KEY (uuid)
    REFERENCES incident (uuid) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ```
- `Incident` inherits `SomeBaseClass` which has `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)`
- As a result Hibernate generated the following constraint:

  ```
  CONSTRAINT fk909a8f2ddd08e84 FOREIGN KEY (uuid)
    REFERENCES somebaseclass (uuid) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ```
- As a result of [HHH-8217 (Make generated constraint names short and non-random)](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8217) in Hibernate 4.2.2 the above two constraint definitions suddenly got the same *name* (Hibernate did only consider the *entity* and the *columns* of the foreign key constraint, not the target entity of the foreign key; note how [`generateName`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/mapping/Constraint.html#generateName-java.lang.String-org.hibernate.mapping.Table-java.util.List-) only takes one `Table` as a parameter)
- And there was the corresponding clash: `Constraint ... already exists`

Changing the `@ManyToMany` to `@OneToMany` fixes this entirely.

By the way, the offending field definition (the one with the `@ManyToMany`) also previously caused me problems with Hibernate Envers' `@Audited`, the reason of which I never understood, and that got resolved now as well. It's a good day. (Not sure if `@Audited` means much for a mapped field, but at least I can have `@Audited` on the class without needing to deal with this field.)